# Activity intent not working on button click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Hello Stackoverflow community!
Recently, a strange error occured to me. It is with a button in my app. When i press it there is nothing happening. No errors, or crashes but also Intent is not functioning. The transition to DeleteAccountActivity is not happening. I don't know why is this happening. The intent which I am using is very simple(passes nothing). Please help me

AccountSettingsActivity.java

```
public class AccountSettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AccountSettingsActivity";
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 4;
    private  String user_id;




    private Context mContext;
    public SectionsStatePagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private Button mDelete;
    User mUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accountsettings);
        mContext = AccountSettingsActivity.this;
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout1);
        mDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        User mUser = new User();
        setupSettingsList();
        setupBottomNavigationView();
        setupFragments();
        getIncomingIntent();

        //setup the backarrow for navigating back to "ProfileActivity"
        ImageView backArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backArrow);
        backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating back to 'ProfileActivity'");
                finish();

                mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DeleteAccountActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                });
                }
        });
    }


    private void deleteAccounts(){


   /*         DatabaseReference deleteUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user_id);
            DatabaseReference deleteUserPhotos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_photos").child(user_id);
            DatabaseReference deleteUserPhotoComments = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("comments").child(user_id);

            deleteUser.removeValue();
            deleteUserPhotos.removeValue();
            deleteUserPhotoComments.removeValue();*/

            // getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
             //   .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                .removeValue();

     /*   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_followers))
                .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .removeValue(); */


    }

    private void getIncomingIntent(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image))
                || intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap))){

            //if there is an imageUrl attached as an extra, then it was chosen from the gallery/photo fragment
            Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingIntent: New incoming imgUrl");
            if(intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.return_to_fragment)).equals(getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment))){

                if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image))){
                    //set the new profile picture
                    FirebaseMethods firebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(AccountSettingsActivity.this);
                    firebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.profile_photo), null, 0,
                            intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image)), null);
                }
                else if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap))){
                    //set the new profile picture
                    FirebaseMethods firebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(AccountSettingsActivity.this);
                    firebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.profile_photo), null, 0,
                            null,(Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap)));
                }

            }

        }

        if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.calling_activity))){
            Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingIntent: received incoming intent from " + getString(R.string.profile_activity));
            setViewPager(pagerAdapter.getFragmentNumber(getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment)));
        }
    }

    private void setupFragments(){
        pagerAdapter = new SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new EditProfileFragment(), getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment)); //fragment 0
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new SignOutFragment(), getString(R.string.sign_out_fragment)); //fragment 1
     //   pagerAdapter.addFragment(new DeleteAccountFragment(), "Delete Account");
    }

    public void setViewPager(int fragmentNumber){
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d(TAG, "setViewPager: navigating to fragment #: " + fragmentNumber);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentNumber);
    }

    private void setupSettingsList(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupSettingsList: initializing 'Account Settings' list.");
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAccountSettings);

        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add(getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment)); //fragment 0
        options.add(getString(R.string.sign_out_fragment)); //fragement 1
  //      options.add("Delete Account");

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: navigating to fragment#: " + position);
                setViewPager(position);
            }
        });

    }


    /**
     * BottomNavigationView setup
     */
    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, this,bottomNavigationViewEx);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }


}
```

DeleteAccountActivity.java

```
public class DeleteAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button yesButton;
    Button cancelButton;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete_account);

        yesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete2);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete3);

        yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deleteAllData();

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AccountSettingsActivity.class);

        }
    });
    }

        public void deleteAllData(){

            DatabaseReference deleteUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("users")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            DatabaseReference deleteUserPhotos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("user_photos")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            DatabaseReference deleteUserPhotoComments = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("user_account_settings")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            DatabaseReference deleteUserFollowing = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("following")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            DatabaseReference deleteUserFollowers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("followers")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            deleteUser.removeValue();
            deleteUserPhotos.removeValue();
            deleteUserPhotoComments.removeValue();
            deleteUserFollowing.removeValue();
            deleteUserFollowers.removeValue();


    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue :

```
Press backarrow (But this will finish the activity)
Press mdelete to trigger the intent. (so no way to trigger intent)
```

Because when you press backarrow, you are setting the listener on `mdelete` which actually has the code to trigger intent and `finish` will kill the activity so no way to trigger intent

Solution : Separate the listeners

```
backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating back to 'ProfileActivity'");
        finish();    
        }
});

mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DeleteAccountActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, change the lines with setting the clickListeners to this:

```
ImageView backArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backArrow);
backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating back to 'ProfileActivity'");
        finish();
        }
});

mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DeleteAccountActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your onCreate() method should look like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accountsettings);
        mContext = AccountSettingsActivity.this;
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout1);
        mDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        User mUser = new User();
        setupSettingsList();
        setupBottomNavigationView();
        setupFragments();
        getIncomingIntent();


mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DeleteAccountActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                });
        //setup the backarrow for navigating back to "ProfileActivity"
        ImageView backArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backArrow);
        backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating back to 'ProfileActivity'");
                finish();
                }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing i can see by skimming through is that the onClick listener for your button that should take you to delete activity is assigned inside the back arrow onClick listener. 
So the only time your delete button is assigned a click listener is when you press the back button, and it wont still assign because you already called 
    finish();
On the activity

Change

```
backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating back to 'ProfileActivity'");
finish();

mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View view) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DeleteAccountActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent); 
} });
```

} });

To

```
backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating back to 'ProfileActivity'");
finish();
```

} });

```
mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View view) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DeleteAccountActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent); 
} });
```

Hope this helps.